# Как в Java в java.util.TimerTask начать цикл сначала?

Tags: java, java-timertask

Фрагмент кода (Основная часть кода находится именно на TimerTask() в run()):

```
import *

public class Game1Controller extends Main {
    private ResourceBundle resources;
    private URL location;
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;
    void initialize()  {
        try {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                public void run () { . . . } //бесполезный для вас код (он бы и не поместился)
            };
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно что-то по типу continue в цикле, чтобы при а==b цикл начинался заново, но не останавливался (как это происходит с методом cancel()).

Comment: Зависит от того что это за цикл. Расскажите подробнее что делает задание.

Comment: В общем это викторина. При нажатии на кнопку и в случае если ответ верный или не верный нужно заканчивать цикл (это не совсем цикл, т.к. тут используется таймер, но я называю его циклом) и начинать новый. Как это выглядит для пользователя: открывается окно, пользователь кликает на кнопку с верным ответом, происходит переход к следующему вопросу

Comment: Да, дело как раз в том, что это не совсем цикл. Нужно определить что меняется в ходе викторины, и по условию вносить эти изменения. Если сможете сократить код и составить пример, то можно будет объяснить подробнее.

Comment: Немного изменил вопрос и максимально сократил код